# Calling Method on Method and beautify output( Chaining Methods)

Tags: python, class, method-chaining

Say for example I have a class Information with methods that works on some dataframe and return dataframe.

```
class Information:

    def __init__(self, ID: str):
        self.ID = ID

    def name(self):
        pd.read_csv(....)
        do something..
        return dataframe
        
    
    def age(self):
        do something.. 
        return datframe

    def pretty_string(self):
        do something.. 
        return string
```

calling I get

student1 = Informations(101)
student1.name

Return Same

```
     ID Name
0   101 Thor
```

student1 = Informations(101)

How can I get only the Name calling another method on method output..
somethinglike

student1.name.pretty_string

```
Thor
```

student1.age.pretty_string

```
1069
```

Not the dataframe in return.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to access to the dataframe column, rows it self. For instance for the `name` attribute I'll suggest:

```py
    @property
    def name(self):
        df = pd.read_csv(....)
        return df["Name"][0]
```

The `@propery` decorator will help to call the method `name` as an attribute of the object itself. So whenever you do:

```py
student1 = Informations(101)
student1.name
```

you will see in the console:

```
Thor
```

Comment: This approach I have been using. However, I sometimes need df as a return and sometimes as a string. For the time being, I am using two methods with different return types(string and df), making two copies of the same methods for all.  So was thinking of another method that can convert it to string return on calling to the main method. so no need to make two copies of the same method..

Answer (score 0):

if you use padas

```
for example:
df.at[0, 'Name']
```

dokumentation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at